# PyQt4: Why I get "ImportError: No module named QtWebkit"?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pyqt4

I have installed Qt 2.4.1, SIP 4.13.3 and PyQt4 4.9.4 on Mac OSX 10.7.5 for Python 3.2.3.

When I tried to `from PyQt4.QtWebkit import QWebPage`, I got: `ImportError: No module named QtWebkit`.

But other modules work fine, such as `from PyQt4 import QtGui`.

I don't know why. What steps am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check webkit installed in your system, for finding path

```
>>> import PyQt4
>>> print PyQt4.__path__
['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4']
```

check you have QtWebkit there. and [check this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922711/importerror-no-module-named-qtwebkit)

Comment: PyQt4.__path__ on my MacBook Pro is /Library/Python/3.2/site-packages/PyQt4. And in that folder I have QtWebKit.so. Does this mean I have QtWebKit installed in my system?

Comment: Jesus  there is a spelling mistake :( `from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage` this should work if you have QtWebKit.so in ur folder :)

Comment: Yes, you're right! Sorry my mistake about the spelling. It works now. Thank you very much!